# How to stop an onChange event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I have a run away onChange() event happening and I cannot seem to figure out how to stop it.

Here is my HTML:

```
<input id="language_french" type="text"
  name="french"
  data-provide="slider"
  data-slider-ticks="[0,1,2]"
  data-slider-min="0"
  data-slider-max="2"
  data-slider-step="1"
  data-slider-precision="0"
  data-slider-value="1"
  data-slider-tooltip="show"
  data-identifier="001^023"
/>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
div#fixBootstrapSliderPluginStyles div.slider.slider-horizontal { margin-bottom: 20px !important; }
div#fixBootstrapSliderPluginStyles div.slider.slider-horizontal div.slider-tick-label-container { margin-left: -52.5px !important; }
div#fixBootstrapSliderPluginStyles div.slider.slider-horizontal div.slider-tick-label-container div.slider-tick-label { width: 105px !important; }
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$("#language_french").on( 'change', function( value ) { alert("clicked"); } );
```

Here is my jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/21L9zLy7/

Upon first click on the slider bar, the event fires. But it continues to fire on all mouse movements as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The control still thinks that you changing its values when you mouse over it. This is because the alert stole focus away from it and it doesn't know the mouse button isn't down.
Don't use alert, use the console instead

```
console.log("clicked");
```

Comment: Ha ha...that was pretty dumb of me. Thanks @Musa :)

Comment: Next question on this very same topic @Musa is how can I capture the clicked value? It comes form the `data-slider-ticks` list.

Comment: `this.getAttribute('data-slider-ticks');`

Comment: Ok, close @Musa -- that returned `[0,1,2]`. How might I capture the value of the clicked tick?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit obvious so I'm hesitant to assume that this is an answer, but it seems that it is activating on a 'change' rather than a click event. Is that what you meant to do?

Comment: Yeah, click does not fire in IE 11 with this plugin tool @knox-flanuer, but thanks for posting.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the fiddler source code for your reference **https://jsfiddle.net/rj1405/21L9zLy7/5/**

As it was explained my @Musa, on mouse move the slider is still having the focus. Hence the alert will be displayed and **any piece of code will run get executed.**

You will get more control through events **slideStop** and **slideStart**.

**slideStop :** Gives you the new value.

**slideStart :** Gives you the old value(start point).

**The values** cane be accessed through

`**$('#language_french').data('slider').getValue();**`

Bellow is the source code.
**Please note some of the external libraries are not loaded so it may not execute.**

```js
$('#language_french').slider().on('slideStart', function(ev){
    originalVal = $('#language_french').data('slider').getValue();
});

$('#language_french').slider().on('slideStop', function(ev){
    var newVal = $('#language_french').data('slider').getValue();
    alert(newVal);
    
});
```

```css
div#fixBootstrapSliderPluginStyles div.slider.slider-horizontal { margin-bottom: 20px !important; }
div#fixBootstrapSliderPluginStyles div.slider.slider-horizontal div.slider-tick-label-container { margin-left: -52.5px !important; }
div#fixBootstrapSliderPluginStyles div.slider.slider-horizontal div.slider-tick-label-container div.slider-tick-label { width: 105px !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="language_french" type="text"
  name="french"
  data-provide="slider"
  data-slider-ticks="[0,1,2]"
  data-slider-min="0"
  data-slider-max="2"
  data-slider-step="1"
  data-slider-precision="0"
  data-slider-value="1"
  data-slider-tooltip="show"
  data-identifier="001^023"
/>
```